# Template member functions, static local variables and destruction order

Tags: c++, templates, memory-management, c++11, static

First of all, sorry for my English:

I've designed a little library to manage the memory my program uses. Mainly it implements a kind of shared object with memory management purposes. I have the following classes (I omit other members and functions that I don't need here to explain my problem):

- A parametric struct called `packet` that contains a subobject of type `T` and a counter:

> ```
> template<class T>
> struct packet
> {
>    T t;
>    unsigned counter;
> };
> ```

- A parametric class called `ptrstack`: a `stack` with a destructor which calls `delete` for each pointer the stack contains, when its destructor is called:

> ```
> template<typename T>
> struct ptrstack : public std::stack<T*>
> {
>   ~ptrstack()
>   {
>       while(!this->empty()) {
>         delete this->top();
>         this->pop();
>       }
>   }
> };
> ```

- A class called `pool` with a static parametric function (and other code, of course) returning a reference to a `ptrstack`:

> ```
> class pool
> {
>    template<class T>
>    using stack_tp = ptrstack<packet<T> >;
>
> public:
>    template<class T>
>    static stack_tp<T>& get()
>    {
>      static stack_tp<T> pool;
>
>      return pool;
>    }
> };
> ```

- Finally, the parametric class `shared_obj`

> ```
> template<typename T>
> class shared_obj
> { /* Members (see below) */ };
> ```

- User classes inherit `shared_obj`:

> ```
> struct internals_t; // definition in a .cpp source code (pImpl idiom).
>
> // `shared_obj` uses only pointer to its type parameter.
> class user_t : public shared_obj<internals_t>
> {
>   // member functions accessing its internal pointer. 
>   // `user_t` is very light. It only mantains a pointer, but it could be used as
>   // a common object.
>   // moreover, I can work with dynamic objects without using new and delete
>   // since the memory is managed by shared_obj
> };
> ```

Construction, assignment/copies and destruction perform fundamentally the following actions:

- Each time a new `shared_obj<T>` is wanted to be created, a `packet<T>*` is created in the heap.
- Each time a `shared_obj<T>` is copied, the counter of its associated packet is incremented.
- Each time the destructor of a `shared_obj<T>` is called, the counter of its associated packet is decremented.
- If the counter of its associated packet reachs 0, its associated pointer is pushed on the stack by means of:

> ```
> pool::get<T>().push(ptr);
> ```

- So, I redefine the first point of this list: when a new `packet<T>*` is wanted to be created, and the pool of its type is empty, a new packet is created in the heap. If the pool isn't empty, I use the "in-place" version of new:

> ```
> new (pool::get<T>().top()) T(args);
> pool::get<T>().pop();
> ```

So, destruction are delegated when the program exits, and all created memory is up to be reused.

Enough explanations!!

**My problem is**: I need any other statics objects of type "`user_t`" (really, different object of different types inheriting `shared_obj`), but any of them produce memory leaks, and I thing for the following reason:

- That static objects are being created before the creation of its associated pools, because of the definition of `packet_pool.get<T>()` for each type is instantiated after the definition: template definitions are instantiated to concrete type in the first pointer of use and not where the template is written. So, the lexical order in my files is different from the definition order in my translated unit.
- In consequence, my static objects are being destructed after its associated pools, because static objects are deleted in inverse order of its construction, and that coincides with the definition order of its translated unit.
- When that static objects are destructed, its associated counter reachs 0 and they try to be pushed in its **destructed** pool. That throws the crash.

My doubt is finally the following:

- What is the concrete "definition order" for instantiated template functions in a translation unit? Are my assumptions correct?

And here a parallel question:

- Can the problem also be related with the fact that the pool is a local static function or the "get" function is itself inlined (because it's a function defined inside its class)? I mean, does each "pool" (each stack) have internal linkage and do I have different `pools` for the same type in different translation units?

Comment: I have a feeling all of this could be reduced to a single 10 line code snippet, and a very short question...

Comment: "parametric" is the wrong word. You mean "template".